# 94 Chevy k1500 5.7L coolant gushing

Tags: chevrolet, cooling-system, coolant-leak

I have coolant gushing out of the bell by the firewall. I replaced the heater core (luckily very easy in this truck). There are no leaks other than from that peep hole. Not on the floor boards and not from any hoses. I can literally see it peeing out the peep hole like it's taunting me (a little humor to steer away from the madness).

I will also say that there is no pressure in the radiator cap, no matter how hot  and a slight thumping in the radiator (which might just be because there's nothing in it after a minute). Also there is a good bit of rust in it which if I had the means to an outside faucet/ hose and place to flush it I would have. Now some of this flushing is already happening due to leak but maybe not to the level needed..

Please help...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not understanding where "bell by the firewall" is? Could you explain that a little better? Is it part of the engine? Or off the firewall itself?

Comment: A photo of the area and a closer one of the "peep" hole may help...

Comment: It is the peephole by the transmission

Comment: Can't put a picture up right now. But it's where the engine meet the tranny. I replaced the heater core hose to the engine and radiator. Flush the entire system and it doesn't seem block up